# If-else JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

Whats wrong with this script? It resets itself and the second div never changes. I'm missing something? I'm thinking I probably need a better way to handle the variable so if someone knows of one that would be awesome. This is my jsfiddle testing script:

```
var lang="de";

$('#en').click(function () {
    lang="en";
});
$('#de').click(function () {
    lang="de";
});
$('#es').click(function () {
    lang="es";
});

function showtext() {
    $('#text').text(lang); 
    if (lang="en") {
        $('#cur').text(lang);
    }
    else if (lang="de") {
        $('#cur').text(lang);
    }
    else if (lang="es") {
        $('#cur').text(lang);
    }
}

showtext();

setInterval(function () {
    showtext();
}, 2000);
```

Demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Su3RC/155/)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851399/javascript-if-statements-not-working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is doing assignment through `=`, for comparison you must use `==`.

```
function showtext() {
    $('#text').text(lang); 
    if (lang == "en") {
        $('#cur').text(lang);
    }
    else if (lang == "de") {
        $('#cur').text(lang);
    }
    else if (lang == "es") {
        $('#cur').text(lang);
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Su3RC/156/)

Comment: omg, I feel so dumb now, I should of seen that, Ive been racking my brain why it wasn't working lol. thanks for helping me see it!

Answer (score 0):

Your comparisons are actually assignments try below:

```
$('#text').text(lang); 
    if (lang=="en"){
        $('#cur').text(lang);
    }
    else if (lang=="de"){
        $('#cur').text(lang);
    }
    else if (lang=="es"){
        $('#cur').text(lang);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an if loop that does exactly nothing (and it uses the wrong comparison operator). Try this instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/Su3RC/158/

```
function showtext() {
    $('#text').text(lang);
    $('#cur').text(lang);
}
```

Comment: I believe he is wanting to learn/fix if-statements, rather than optimize his snippet of code.

Comment: Fair enough. I wasn't sure.